# Is there a standard Python function that takes any number of arguments and does nothing?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm doing some functional programming in Python, and It'd be really useful if I had a function that took any number of arguments but didn't do anything, to use as a default value for a few things. I was wondering if anybody knew of the existence of one, or how I could make one on my own.

EDIT after seeing responses: Also, I'm new to python, so any elaboration on exotic syntax would be super helpful. What do the stars mean?

Comment: shame that the name `id` is already in use.

Comment: @Elazar: If you're thinking about the typical functional-language function, wouldn't want a function named `id` to return `None`, you'd want it to return its argument. (Also, you can just call it `identity` or `ident`. I have a `def identity(x): return x` in more than one project…)

Comment: @abarnert -- What do you know, I have that one too.  Maybe we should package it and put it on PyPI

Comment: @abarnert you are right. I am simply confused. and, I wish `id` *was* identity (as you noted, you saw it in more than one project)

Comment: @mgilson: It was in `functional` (as `functional.id`), but that module is now dead. I have my own fork of it (https://github.com/abarnert/functional), but because I'm not sure about the licensing issues involved (as far as I can tell, some of it is under PSF, some of it has no explicit license and may or may not be public domain) I haven't done anything with it… But you can get it as `more_functools.identity`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create your own:

```
def noop(*args, **kw): pass
```

This takes any number of positional and keyword arguments and does nothing at all. [`pass` signifies an empty python block](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-pass_stmt); it works anywhere Python expects a `block`, including loops, `if` statements and `try` statements.

Python callables always return *something* (it is a language requirement); if no explicit return value is given `None` is returned.

The `*` and `**` indicate arbitrary length parameters; you can pass in 0 or more positional parameters and the `args` name will represent a tuple of them, and 0 or more keyword arguments, and they are captured in the `kw` dictionary.

From the [function definition documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions):

> If the form “`*identifier`” is present, it is initialized to a tuple receiving any excess positional parameters, defaulting to the empty tuple. If the form “`**identifier`” is present, it is initialized to a new dictionary receiving any excess keyword arguments, defaulting to a new empty dictionary.

Simple demo of `*` and `**` parameters:

```
>>> def f(*args, **kw): return (args, kw)
... 
>>> f('foo', 'bar', spam='eggs', monty='python')
(('foo', 'bar'), {'monty': 'python', 'spam': 'eggs'})
```

For functional programming, if you need the arguments to be returned *as is* you need to think about what you need returning; a one-argument function would return just that argument and for anything that needs to take 2 or more arguments and return them all, you'd have to return those arguments as a tuple:

```
def identity(arg): return arg

def plural_identity(*args): return args
```

Demo:

```
>>> identity('foobar')
'foobar'
>>> plural_identity('spam', 'eggs')
('spam', 'eggs')
```

Comment: You could do it as a lambda too, if that is more friendly to the context.

Comment: Does this really do nothing?  It returns `None` which is in fact doing *something*.  Of course, I think OP might need to give a little more information on what doing *nothing* actually means... (anyway, +1 ... I think this is probably the best answer you could give to this question)

Comment: a function can't do any less than that, in python... unless it has a time machine I guess.

Comment: All Python functions return something; they wouldn't be functions otherwise. They also have to execute a `RETURN_VALUE` opcode or they won't return. So, I think this is a pretty good definition for "do nothing". (IIRC, the tutorial even describes `pass` exactly that way.)

Comment: @mgilson: callables always have to return *something*; `None` is the closest you can get to 'nothing'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Right, but in a functional context, "do nothing" could be interpreted as "return it's arguments" (if I understand functional programming properly).  Then you could insert it into a long pipeline of functions and not need to worry about anything.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Anyway, my point wasn't to criticize this answer.  I was more trying to point out that the question is a little ill-posed for python and perhaps needs a little more thought to make it more clear what OP is actually looking for.

Comment: Actually, at least in CPython, you _can_ write a function that literally "does nothing": `types.FunctionType(types.CodeType(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, b'', (), (), (), '', '', 0, b''), globals())`. But calling this will give you a `SystemError` (or, if you're unlucky, a segfault) because its "first opcode" doesn't exist. (For 2.x, remove one of the initial `0`s.)

Comment: @mgilson If we're in it, it can't return it's arguments - real function have exactly single argument.

Comment: @Elazar: Says who? Lots of functional languages define `function` as something of either 0 or more or 1 or more arguments, and that fits the mathematical description. And almost every language that requires exactly 1 argument does automatic currying, so you don't need multiple arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `None` is (somehow) equivalent to `Unit`. I think you should note that. "does nothing" is correct here as a python term, not as a functional programming term. ML equivalent: `fun f () = ();`

Comment: @abarnert only if you regard tuple as many arguments. Mathemtical definition: function F is a subset of AxB. not AxBxCx...

Comment: @Elazar: It depends on which definition you use. "Relation" is usually defined as a cartesian product of any number of sets (which is why there's a specific term "binary relation"). If you define "function" in terms of "relation", `AxBxC` is a function iff it's left-total on `AxB` and right-unique on `C`. If you define it in terms of "binary relation", it's not a function, period (unless you've defined things such that `AxBxC === (AxB)xC`, in which case you effectively have auto-currying). Unfortunately, many texts use the term "relation" in the definition, but mean "binary relation"…